# Let element take the remaining height without using display:table-row and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, height, vertical-scrolling

A rather usual case [as demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/g6j3j/) is, as far as i have learned by my own research, usually solved by applying either:

- `display:table-row` to `.titleBar` and `.content` and applying `display:table` to the parent
- `position:absolute` to `.content` with all four axis set to 0, so that the element stretches out

Unfortunately, in my actual live environment, i cannot apply either of those due to specific reasons.

Is there a way to have `.content` stretch to the remaining available height without ignoring the height of `.titleBar` (as you can see in the example by scrolling down)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change height property in these elements like this?

```
.outer .titleBar {
    height: 5%;
}
.outer .content {
    height: 95%;
}
```